# SwiftUI: How to put a line break within ForEach loop where it repeats a view in it

Tags: swift, layout, foreach, view, swiftui

I have a dynamic SwiftUI view where I pass information through parameter. After, I try to make copies of the view using ForEach loop. The views appear as usual vertically in a Stack. However, I would like to present the all views in three different lines.
Could anyone please present a  efficient solution?

I want this design:

[image: And I want this:]

But I have got this:

[image: I have got this:]

My code:

```
struct AllDaysView: View {
    @Binding var hasMenuShown: Bool
    var days: [String] = NextDaysView().days

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MenuBarView(hasMenuShown: $hasMenuShown)
            ForecastButtonsView()
            HStack {
                ForEach(days, id: \.self) { day in
                    SingleDaySummaryView(day: day)
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, let's make a way to divide the array in groups of three.

```swift
extension Array {
    func dividedIntoGroups(of i: Int = 3) -> [[Element]] {
        var copy = self
        var res = [[Element]]()
        while copy.count > i {
            res.append( (0 ..< i).map { _ in copy.remove(at: 0) } )
        }
        res.append(copy)
        return res
    }
}
```

Change the `days` var:

```swift
var days: [String] = NextDaysView().days.dividedIntoGroups(of: 3)
```

Now, let's make the new code for `body`:

```swift
VStack {
    MenuBarView(hasMenuShown: $hasMenuShown)
    ForecastButtonsView()
    ForEach(days, id: \.self) { dayRow in
        HStack {
            ForEach(dayRow, id: \.self) { day in
                SingleDaySummaryView(day: day)
            }
        }
    }
    Spacer()
}
```

In this code, you can easily change the number of views per row, but it seems quite difficult to make it really dynamic. When you want to do that, you could use `GeometryReader` to get the screen width, but to calculate the number of views per row, you will of course also need the width of one view, and *that*'s tricky. This article may contain information that could lead to a solution: https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-1/

I couldn't really test this code, because I'm not working on my Mac right now, but hopefully it works or will at least help you!

Comment: The logic seems great. However, I could not run the code as it gives an error in the nested ForEach loop says "Cannot convert value of type '(String) -> SingleDaySummaryView' to expected argument type '(_) -> _'". Could you please have a look on it?

Comment: Hey really thanks. It worked with little modification.